# Using for-loop to Implement deletion in Array-based List

Tags: c++, for-loop, data-structures

I’m writing a code to implement Array-based List in C++ using class and template. 
Here’s the code:

```
template <typename T>
struct ArrayList
{
    T arr[LIST_LEN];
    int curPos;
    int numOfData;
};
//declare base class
template <typename T>
class ListObj
{
public:
    ListObj(ArrayList<T>* plist);
    void insert(ArrayList<T>* plist, T data);
    T remove(ArrayList<T>* plist);
    int cnt(ArrayList<T>* plist);
};
//declare members
template <typename T>
ListObj<T>::ListObj(ArrayList<T>* plist)
{
   plist->curPos = -1;
   plist->numOfData = 0;
}
template <typename T>
void ListObj<T>::insert(ArrayList<T>* plist, T data)
{
    if (plist->numOfData >= LIST_LEN)
    {
        cout << "Out of Capacity!" << endl;
        return;
    }
    plist->arr[plist->numOfData] = data;
    plist->numOfData++;
}
template <typename T>
T ListObj<T>::remove(ArrayList<T>* plist)
{
    int rpos = plist->curPos;
    int num = plist->numOfData;
    T rdata = plist->arr[rpos];

    for (int i = rpos; i < num - 1; i++)
       plist->arr[i] = plist->arr[i + 1];
    plist->numOfData--;
    plist->curPos--;
    return rdata;
}
template <typename T>
int ListObj<T>::cnt(ArrayList<T>* plist)
{
    return plist->numOfData;
}
//miscellaneous functions
template <typename T>
bool LFirst(ArrayList<T>* plist, T* pdata)
{
    if (plist->numOfData == 0)
        return false;
    plist->curPos = 0;
    *pdata = plist->arr[0];
    return true;
}
template <typename T>
bool LNext(ArrayList<T>* plist, T* pdata)
{
   if (plist->curPos >= plist->numOfData - 1)
       return false;
   plist->curPos++;
   *pdata = plist->arr[plist->curPos];
   return true;
}
```

And, here’s the code for main function.

```
int main(void)
  {       
     //initialization
     ArrayList<int> list;
     ListObj<int> l(&list);
     int data;

     //insert 5 integers
     l.insert(&list, 11);
     l.insert(&list, 22);
     l.insert(&list, 22);
     l.insert(&list, 33);
     l.insert(&list, 44);

    //show the number of data in array
   cout << "Current # of Data:" << l.cnt(&list) << endl;

   for (int i = 0; i < list.numOfData; i++)
   {
       cout << list.arr[i] << endl;
   }
   cout << endl;

   //delete certain data value
   if (LFirst(&list, &data))
   {
       if (data == 22)
          l.remove(&list);

       while (LNext(&list, &data))
       {
           if(data==22)
               l.remove(&list);
       }
   }

   cout << "Current # of Data:" << l.cnt(&list) << endl;

   for (int i = 0; i < list.numOfData; i++)
   {
       cout << list.arr[i] << endl;
   }
   cout << endl;
   system("pause");
   return 0;
}
```

This code worked as I intended. But I changed the code for remove() like this  using for-loop.

```
  template <typename T>
  T ListObj<T>::remove(ArrayList<T>* plist,T target)
  {
     for (int i = 0; i < plist->numOfData; i++)
     {
       if (plist->arr[i] == target)
       {
          int rpos = i;
          int num = plist->numOfData;
          T rdata = plist->arr[rpos];

          for (int i = rpos; i < num - 1; i++)
              plist->arr[i] = plist->arr[i + 1];
          plist->numOfData--;
          return rdata;
       }
    }
}
```

So, above function will be called like this;
l.remove(&list, 22);//22 is target value

In this code, remove() function is supposed to be called twice to delete target data (22 in this case). 
Therefore, if the code work properly, result should be 11 33 44. But the result is 11 22 33 44. That is, this function called only once. I tried several things to fix the problem but those didn’t work. If someone pick the bug or error in my code, I really appreciate.

Comment: [Talk to your rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging), and walk through your code, one line at a time, explaining every step to your rubber duck, with a diagram of what each variable contains. The bug is very obvious, and your rubber duck should be able to explain it to you.

Comment: "Rubber Duck" : I learned a new way to debug.

Comment: Apart from the bug, `ListObj` serves no purpose since `ArrayList<T>* plist` is passed in every operation. Ideally `ListObj` should store reference to `ArrayList<T>` inside it and all the operations should be accessed via `ListObj's` instance itself without having to pass `ArrayList<T>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just fixed problem. my error is wrong application of iterator. so I changed for loop like this and got the result what I wanted.

```
template <typename T>
T ListObj<T>::remove(ArrayList<T>* plist,T target)
{
    for (int i = plist->numOfData; i >0; i--)
    {
        if (plist->arr[i] == target)
        {
            int rpos = i;
            int num = plist->numOfData;
            rdata = plist->arr[rpos];
            for (int i = rpos; i < num - 1; i++)
                plist->arr[i] = plist->arr[i + 1];
            plist->numOfData--;
        }
    }
}
```

I really appreciate to guys gave me advice and tips.

Answer (score 0):

Your `remove` method `return`s after it removed the first element. I am not 100% sure, but I think you should change it to:

```
template <typename T>
T ListObj<T>::remove(ArrayList<T>* plist,T target)
{
    T rdata;
    for (int i = 0; i < plist->numOfData; i++)
    {
        if (plist->arr[i] == target)
        {
            int rpos = i;
            int num = plist->numOfData;
            rdata = plist->arr[rpos];
            for (int i = rpos; i < num - 1; i++)
                plist->arr[i] = plist->arr[i + 1];
            plist->numOfData--;
        }
    }
    return rdata;
}
```

Comment: `rdata` isn't in scope where you're trying to return it.

Comment: @SeihyungOh what do you mean with didnt work? I edited to fix the mistake pointed out be Barry. But actually I dont really understand what you want to return, if none or more than one element was found, isnt `rdata==target` anyhow?

Comment: @tobi303 I solved problem thanks to your advice. my error is

Comment: @SeihyungOh if you found the solution you might want to post it as an answer